# Операции с массивами

Tags: php

```
$card = array ( 'Phones' => 
    [ "Apple" => 
                 [ 'price' => 5000,
                   'count' => 2,
                   'disc' => 500
                 ],
      "Sumsung" => 

                 [ 'price' => 4000,
                   'count' => 0,
                   'disc' => 0
                 ],
      "Xiaomi" => 
                  ['price' => 3500,
                   'count' => 1,
                   'disc' => 300
                  ]

    ],                   'TVs' => 
    [ "LG" => 
                  [ 'price' => 10000,
                    'count' => 1,
                    'disc' => 1000
                  ],
      "Sumsung" => 
                  [ 'price' => 8000,
                    'count' => 2,
                    'disc' => 0
                  ],
    ]
             );
```

Есть массив корзины, нужно посчитать общую сумму, price - цена товара, count - количество, disc - скидка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужна на выходе сумма за всю корзину, можно сделать простую функцию:

```
function totalPrice($card) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($card as $category => $items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $total += $item['price'] * $item['count'] - $item['disc'];
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Тогда если взять ваш массив на выходе получим:

```
var_dump(totalPrice($card)); // 37700
```

Comment: Спасибо, такая универсальная функция мне подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$priceAll = 0;
$countAll = 0;
$discAll = 0;

foreach($card['Phones'] as $product){

   $priceAll += $product['price'];
   $countAll += $product['count']; 
   $discAll += $product['disc']; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, такой вариант будет самым простым, но может есть еще какие-нибудь другие, "поумнее"?

Comment: @Vuland, можно, но зачем усложнять? Если бы массив был бы индексированный, было бы больше вариантов

Comment: Там еще и телевизоры :)

Comment: @Vuland поумнее предлагают код на основе ВАШЕГО неумного, а тут за вас сделали из НИЧЕГО.